# Was versteht man unter "direktem Umkreis"?

Tags: meaning

Mir ist aufgefallen, dass jeder etwas anderes unter "direktem Umkreis" zu verstehen scheint. Manchmal ist damit die 5 Minuten entfernte Bushaltestelle gemeint, ein anderes Mal die 1,5h Stunden entfernte Stadt am anderen Ende des Bundeslandes.

Gibt es eine autoritative Definition oder engere Einrahmung, auf die man sich hier berufen kann?

Comment: Urbi et orbi :-) ... ist mir auch aufgefallen ... nicht nur in meinem direkten Umkreis. Hängt von den Umständen, dem Zusammenhang, dem Thema ab. Man stelle sich den direkten Umkreis des Sonnensystems vor ... Wäre ein "Nein" akzeptabel ?

Comment: Ja, gibt es. Ich habe gerade entschieden, dass der direkte Umkreis alles umfasst, das man in 25 Minuten mit dem Fahrrad erreichen kann.

Comment: @Carsten, das führt zu interessanten Formen, wenn man in der Mitte eines Berges wohnt. In die eine Richtung erreicht man viel mehr in 25min als in die andere ;)

Comment: @a_donda selbstredend ist ein "nein" eine legitime Antwort auf eine Ja/Nein-Frage, sonst waere sie ja rhetorisch und damit entgegen der Regeln dieser Plattform ;)
Also ist das ein absolut relatives Mass was voellig subjektiv definiert wird? Woher aber wissen Menschen dann, was sie darunter in etwa zu verstehen haben?

Comment: Na aus dem Zusammenhang. Wenn der nicht reicht, nachfragen. "Direktes Umfeld" kann sich auf die nächste Apotheke beziehen, den Nachbarstern, die Bushaltestelle, gleichgesinnte Hobbyisten, oder auf etwas ganz Abstraktes, das es in meinem Umfeld immer wieder/überhaupt nicht/freitags nie gibt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die "autorative Definition" gibt es nicht.

Das Verständnis über den "direkten Umkreis" hängt vom Gesprächskontext und dem Duktus des Gegenübers ab und ist kann nur in Relation zur Beschreibung "das ist weit weg" in diesem Kontext verstanden werden: es ist signifikant näher dran. Und der Gesprächspartner ist in der Regel der Meinung, dass er bzw. die konkrete Person wenig Aufwand hat, in diesem "direkten Umkreis" eine Aufgabe zu erledigen/Ziel zu erreichen/...

Beispiele, auch zu ähnlich schwammigen Formulierungen:

- im Rahmen von Coronoa-Ausgangsbeschränkungen [entschied](https://www.l-iz.de/leben/faelle-unfaelle/2020/04/Freizeitaktivitaeten-in-Coronazeiten-15-Kilometer-Umkreis-laut-OVG-Bautzen-325605) das OVG Sachsen, dass der "direkte Umkreis" in dieser Anordnung mit 15 km zum Wohnort zu definieren sei
- im Rahmen eines Unfalls auf dem Arbeitsweg ist keinerlei Umkreis erlaubt, hier kommt es auf den Zweck an, zu dem vom kürzesten Weg abgewichen wird ([einfache Darstellung](https://www.dguv.de/de/versicherung/wegeunfaelle/index.jsp) bei DGUV)
- [EStG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/estg/BJNR010050934.html#BJNR010050934BJNG023900140) nennt " haushaltsnahe Beschäftigungsverhältnisse"

  - Welches Aufgabengebiet als "haushaltsnah" zu verstehen ist, muss im Zweifel ein Gericht klären - obgleich die meisten Menschen eines Kulturkreises da eine sehr ähnliche Vorstellung haben.
- Die Abgabenordnung definiert, was ein [Angehöriger](https://dejure.org/gesetze/AO/15.html) ist, u.a. auch "8. Personen, die durch ein auf längere Dauer angelegtes Pflegeverhältnis mit häuslicher Gemeinschaft wie Eltern und Kind miteinander verbunden sind (Pflegeeltern und Pflegekinder)"

  - Das ist für weitere Gesetzestexte nötig um dort nur zu schreiben "für Angehörige gilt"
  - Je nach Situation werden "Angehörige" als der direkte Umkreis/das direkte Umfeld einer Person bezeichnet.

Comment: Im zweiten Beispiel ist doch sicher *Umweg* statt *Umkreis* gemeint.

Comment: @Olafant: beides: ich darf keinen Umweg machen, auch nicht im unmittelbaren Umkreis der Orte, die ich anfahren darf.